# PostgreSQL NOT NULL foreign key and default value with sequence

Tags: postgresql

I'm analyzing a following PostgreSQL schema:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ref_email_type_ref_email_type_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE ref_email_type
(
  ref_email_type_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('ref_email_type_ref_email_type_id_seq'::regclass),
  description character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT ref_email_type_pkey PRIMARY KEY (ref_email_type_id)
)

CREATE TABLE email
(
  email_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('email_email_id_seq'::regclass),
  ref_email_type_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('email_ref_email_type_id_seq'::regclass),
  email_address character varying(100),
  CONSTRAINT email_pkey PRIMARY KEY (email_id),
  CONSTRAINT email_ref_email_type_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (ref_email_type_id)
      REFERENCES ref_email_type (ref_email_type_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Does it make any sense to have `email.ref_email_type_id` declared with `DEFAULT nextval('email_ref_email_type_id_seq'::regclass)` in case of `NOT NULL` and existing constraint:

```
  CONSTRAINT email_ref_email_type_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (ref_email_type_id)
      REFERENCES ref_email_type (ref_email_type_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

Comment: Short anser: No, it makes no sense. A foreign key is intended to refer to a (primary) key in (another) table. It cannot be *both* the other key and the value supplied by the sequence. If it *were* the value supplied by the sequence, chances would be big (~1.0) that this value would violate the FK constraint.

Comment: @joop chances are so big that they are actually *100%*. Transactions does not apply to sequence generation in PostgreSQL, `nextval()` always executed atomically, and never rolled back (thus always provides a unique value, but usually with gaps in the table).

Comment: Note 1.0 := 100% (there is a *small* chance of actually hitting an existing key value)

Comment: @joop no, actually not *If it were the value supplied by the sequence* (as you started your sentence). If both values are supplied by the sequence, It will always be a miss, even with high concurrency.

Comment: @pozs : you probably didn't notice that there were two *different* sequences involved (one for the PK, one for the referring FK) ?

Comment: @joop I did notice, but the FK one refers to the same sequence, the other 1 doesnt even get involved in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that doesn't make any sense at all.

It won't do any harm either, since the default value will probably never be used.